# How to alter provisioning scripts for SqlSyncProvider?

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Is there a convenient way to alter the database provisioning scripts before provisioning occurs, possibly without manually altering the script as a string but in a structured way?

I’m using SqlSyncProvider for a SQL database. What I would like to do is to add one table to Sync metadata for every scope that is created. This table would map a GUID to the corresponding table name and PK value. The table triggers would also need to be altered to automatically insert new rows to this additional tracking table.

Can anyone tell me what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

most of the provisioning functionalities are internal to Sync Framework and the Script() method is the only publicly exposed API for you to grab the provisioning commands and apply yourself.

likewise, what you're trying to achieve is actually outside of the sync framework functionality so you would be better off firing them off as a separate process than the sync framework provisioning itself.